# android map application not running in device

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run android map application on my samsung s2 device but it is not running .
i have given all the permission in manifest file and also generated the api key from google console but still it is not working.

I have also linked the library project to my app .

following is the log cat entries

```
 01-14 15:38:39.219: W/dalvikvm(13258): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1563 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;

    01-14 15:38:39.219: D/dalvikvm(13258): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e

    01-14 15:38:39.227: D/AndroidRuntime(13258): Shutting down VM

    01-14 15:38:39.227: W/dalvikvm(13258): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bb22a0)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4835)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1920)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at com.example.mapapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)

    01-14 15:38:39.227: E/AndroidRuntime(13258):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest file :>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.mapapp.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapapp.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission             android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="Api key"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: have you referenced google play srvices library project in your android project?

Comment: @raghunandan i have referenced google play services lib.

Answer (score 0):

Your project doesn't seem to reference google play services.
Import the library project into your workspace
- Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project from "C:\Users**your path**\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services"

- Be careful brose only upto - google_play_services and not upto google_play_services_lib

- Select your project (not the Google Play services Library Project), then right click on it. Select Properties > Select Android tab from top left corner > In the Library Section Press Add Select google-play-services_lib project and press OK. You can see a green tick in the Library Section left to Google Play Service Library if everything is done right. 

 after that you can clean your workspace and it should work

Use [ReferencingLibraryProject](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) and [Setup](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) if you need to research more.

also add this to your manifest as a child to the application

> meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: can you please update with your manifest/part of your manifest? This error is due to not finding the play services so is quite possible something is still missing somewhere. Also, make sure that when you imported google play services project into workspace, you checked Copy Project into workspace

Comment: check out now i have added manifest file now .. please help me as i am thinking about making an mapping application for my minor project and i have stuck at this point please help me sir ...

Comment: where i should add <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: did u mean i should replace the api key with @integer/google_play_services_version

Comment: no, dont replace the api key. Put it right above the meta-data for the map. Also, please remove your api key from the post. never leave it public

Comment: don't forget to chose a correct answer. A lot of people search through questions with answers and it also helps those that helped you

Comment: once again thanks in our national language "SHUKRIYA"(thanks) sir

Comment: thats a whole different question. Please ask a question and link it to me and i will gladly help, but in the way stackoverflow its meant to be used, not chatting in comments :)